# Can't sign with key alias with white space in fastlane?

Tags: android, alias, keytool, fastlane

Fastlane can't sign when alias has white space.Is there any way for that.I tried to change my key alias,but it is not success.

```
[15:00:48]: ▸ Only one alias can be specified
[15:00:48]: ▸ Please type jarsigner -help for usage

desc "Build and Sign APK"
  lane :build do |options|
    gradle(task: "clean")
    gradle(task: "assemble")
    sign_apk(
      keystore_path: "${HOME}/keystores/mykeystore.jks",
      alias: "my app",
      storepass: options[:storepass],
      tsa: "http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc316",
      keypass: options[:keypass],
      )
    zipalign(apk_path: "#{lane_context[SharedValues::SIGNED_APK_PATH]}")
    gradle(task: "test")
    slack(message: "Android Build Success: Test App", success: true)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, Fastlane not accept space ( " " ) in key alias.So, I have to changed existing alias to remove spaces.To remove spaces,

```
keytool -changealias -keystore yourkeystore.jks -alias 'my keystore' -destalias mynewkeystore.
```

If you use Jenkins as build process for automation, when setting up Project in Jenkins Server, give Project Name without space.That is important.